# Pass Data from ViewController to NSObject

Tags: objective-c, swift, segue, viewcontroller, nsobject

I have a swift class Jammingue in which there is an NSObject in objective-c, called tryagain. I know how to pass data between swift viewcontrollers using protocols, but an added element here is the NSObject rather than ViewController as well as the Objective-C element. Can one use protocols in a similar way? This is what I have:

```
protocol predesignedDelegate{
func sendPredesignedFunction(info: [String])
}

class Jammingue: NSViewController{
var delegate: passDelegate? = nil
var predesignedArray = []

func doDelegateStuff(){
    if let delegate = delegate{
        delegate.sendPredesignedFunction(predesignedArray)

    }

}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let second = segue.destinationController as?  SecondViewController{
        second.representedObject = predesignedArray
    }
}`
```

The problem is destinationController is only for viewcontrollers, and on the other side of the segue, in the objective-c NSObject, I can't use the same commands to retrieve the data. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear. I **think** you're asking how to pass a custom object that's a subclass of NSObject between your view controllers in a segue.

If you have a custom subclass of NSObject, then use that class type instead of NSObject. The Objective-C header might look like this:

```
@interface MyCustomNSObject: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) //properties of your object go here...

- (void) someMethod;  //your object's method(s) go here.
@end
```

Then in your Swift code, declare your object as being of type MyCustomNSObject instead of NSObject:

In your SecondViewController class, declare a property of that custom type:

```
class SecondViewController: NSViewController
{
  var theCustomObject: MyCustomNSObject
  //The other stuff for SecondViewController goes here
}
```

Then in your Jammingue class:

```
class Jammingue: NSViewController
{
  var tryAgain: MyCustomNSObject

  // blah blah blah...
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
  {
    if let second = segue.destinationController as?  SecondViewController
    {
        second.representedObject = predesignedArray
      second.customObject = tryAgain
    }
  }
}
```

Now both your Jammingue class and your SecondViewController class have instance variables of type MyCustomNSObject, so you can pass your custom object to your destination view controller.

Comment: Thanks for posting such a thorough answer. It looks like it will work! Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is totally what I was asking. All I am looking for is to be able to reference a variable initialized and defined in a ViewController in its corresponding NSObject, probably less complicated than what you posted.

Comment: what do you mean "... in its corresponding NSObject..."?

Comment: There is an NSObject as a subclass of my viewController, and I would like to be able for the viewController to pass data to the NSObject.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. An NSObject can't be a subclass of your view controller. That's like saying that you are your own grandmother. Do you mean that the view controller has an NSObject as an instance variable?

Comment: Yes. I think I just figured it out. I just needed a bridging file, in which I imported the header file, so I could call a method from the objective-c NSObject.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of sensical xcode terminology, and I am grateful that you kept helping.